# Notation for inverse of pull back

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, notation, homology-cohomology

I am writing a proof where I need to keep tracks of pull back maps between cohomology groups. 
It happens that one of the pull backs is an isomorphism and its inverse appears often in the proof. Is there a good notation for this?

So far I have simply used $(f^*)^{-1}$, but this makes my formulas look quite messy and ugly. What cpuld I use instead?
In particular, would $f_*:=(f^*)^{-1}$ be a good notation?

Comment: I think $(f^*)^{-1}$ is the correct notation unless this inverse is induced by a map of spaces $f^{-1}$ which is a homotopy inverse to $f$. You may as well just declare $\phi:=(f^*)^{-1}$ if you want to introduce slicker notation.

Comment: @Tyrone so what if $f$ is a quotient map, for example from the interval to the circle

Comment: What about this case? You want to discuss an isomorphism of path components? The lowercase star is generally reserved for covariantly induced maps, with the upper case star being used for contravariantly induced maps. Since this notation is so standard I would suggest not trying to go change it. Maybe write $\phi=f^*$ so that you can write $\phi^{-1}=(f^*)^{-1}$?